# What am I doing wrong in this continuity check?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, convergence-divergence, continuity

I want to show that the function $f$ is **discontiunous**. $f$ is defined as follows:

$$f(x,y) :=
  \begin{cases} 
   (x^2+y^2)\cdot\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}})    & , (x, y) \neq (0,0) \\
   0  &, \text{ otherwise}\\
  \end{cases}
$$

To check for multidimensional contiunity, I considered checking if

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(x_0+h\cdot e_j) - f(x_0)}{h}}$$

exists and is the same number for each dimension.

Let's start by checking $j = 1$, we get:

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(h, 0) - 0}{h}} = \frac{h²\cdot{\sin(\frac{1}{h})}}{h} = 0 $$

But analogously, for $j = 2$, we also get

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0}{\frac{f(0, h) - 0}{h}} = \frac{h²\cdot{\sin(\frac{1}{h})}}{h} = 0 $$

**Whoops.** I accidentally showed the opposite of what I intended to show, and according to the problem, this must be wrong. But what exactly did I do wrong?

**EDIT:** Silly me. I obviously didn't have enough coffee today. I just realized that I'm asked to show that its partial derivatives aren't continuous, $f$ clearly seems to be continuous. I'm not sure about which answer to pick now, so I'll just mark the first answer as correct (as it made me re-read the problem). :)

Comment: the limits you are computing are directional derivatives. continuity involves a different limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm mistaken but the function appears to be continuous at $0$ since:

$0\le(x^{2}+y^{2})\lvert\sin(\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^{2}+y^{2}}})\rvert\le(x^{2}+y^{2})$

and the function is certainly continuous everywhere else. Notice that if $x>0$ then the partial derivative in the $x$ direction at $(x,0)$ is:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(x,0)=2x\sin(\frac{1}{x})-\cos(\frac{1}{x})$

but at $(0,0)$ the partial derivative in the $x$ direction is:

$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0,0)=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{f(t,0)}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}\frac{t^{2}\sin(\frac{1}{\lvert t\rvert})}{t}=\lim_{t\to0}t\sin(\frac{1}{\lvert t\rvert})=0$.

A similar calculation will show the $y$ partial derivatives near $(0,0)$ are not continuous.